# Image transformation : converting an line to an arc

Tags: computer-vision, transformation

I am looking for an image transformation which can convert a line into an arc. My ultimate goal is to generate curved text of "Devanagari script".

Please be kind, I have looked and search on google and not able to find anything.

Comment: If you add an example, it will be easier to understand what you meant by an arc. Also, does the "line" in your question stand for an edge fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def transform_desire(image,curveIntensity):
'''
will convert image to arc form.
im1 : image.
curveIntensity : How much curved text you desired.
'''
im1 = image
ratio = 0.0001*curveIntensity

## calculate the desired width of the image.
height,width,channel = im1.shape

x = np.linspace(0,width,width).astype(int)
y = (ratio * ((x-(width/2))**2)).astype(int)
## corrosponding to an x every point will get shifted by y amount.

## time to shift.

## create canvas for new image.

adder = 0

if ratio >= 0:
    adder = max(y)
else:
    adder = (-1)*min(y)

retImage = (np.ones((height+adder,width, channel))*0).astype(np.uint8)

if ratio >= 0:
    adder = 0

for xs in range(width):
    ys = y[xs]
    for t in range(height):
        retImage[t+ys+adder,xs,:] = im1[t,xs,:]

return retImage
```

This worked for me. Please help yourself out, if you need this.